# Cell background exceeds cell height

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I have a TableView with several columns and rows.
This is an excerpt of the CSS:

```
.table-view {
    -fx-font-size: 8.0pt;
}

.table-row-cell {
    -fx-cell-size: 1.8em;
}
```

In the cell factory is:

```
StringBuilder style = new StringBuilder();
if (item.getWeight() != null) {
    style.append("-fx-font-weight: ").append(item.getWeight()).append("; ");
}
if (item.getTextColor() != null) {
    style.append("-fx-text-fill: ").append(item.getTextColor().toString().replace("0x","#")).append("; ");
}
if (item.getBackgroundColor() != null) {
    style.append("-fx-background-color: ").append(item.getBackgroundColor().toString().replace("0x","#")).append("; ");
}
setStyle(style.toString());
```

Now, the problem is that when I set a background color the background gets larger than the cell height.

[image: Look at different heights]

I do not find where the problem is.

Comment: I do not succeed in creating a minimal reproduceable example, because I cannot find the rule behind.It does not happen with every cell having a specific background defined.
Moreover, the behaviour changes when rows with background are scrolled ot of the visible area and scrolled back again (i.e. rows appearing ok before may now have the background too large ...). Again, I cannot find the rule.
However, the phenomenon seems to disappear if I set
.table-row-cell {
    -fx-cell-size: 2.0em;
}

Comment: It seems that using
tableView.setFixedCellSize(1.8)
instead of styles does the trick.

Comment: In the FXML file look under Layouts at the values of Pref Width and Height and the Max Width and Height Also CSS and inline styling play a role here one over rides the other I forget which is the dominate value but that may be the issue if you are mixing both concepts